# How to create a WPF Shape Editor?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, editor, geometry

I'm trying to create a WPF Shape (PolyLine) editor, which is a control that I want to use to, edit shapes in a canvas.

What the editor needs to do is to be able to display the points and lines of the shape and to move those around.

Can anyone provide me with a idea of how I can accomplish this, or a starting point? I haven't found anything related to how I could do this, so far.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is good series of texts about this on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/)

[WPF Diagram Designer - Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx)

[WPF Diagram Designer - Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part2.aspx)

[WPF Diagram Designer - Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part3.aspx)

[WPF Diagram Designer - Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx)

Comment: You have your links to part 2 & 3 reversed.

Comment: There's also a part 4: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I also liked the WPF DrawTools article on CodeProject, which has a very nicely formatted set of source classes. It provides a simpler example of outline shapes - ellipse, rectangle, line, polyline and text. Unfortunately, it was deleted in 2015, as someone just pointed out to me.

A [copy of the article is available through the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508131046/https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22776/WPF-DrawTools) but the linked source code has been deleted along with the original article. The article includes class diagrams and enough detail to give you a good idea of the overall design.

Nowadays I think it's worth looking at [Kimono Designer](https://blog.xamarin.com/introducing-the-kimono-designer-for-skiasharp/), although it seems to have been announced to a lot of excitement and the [code](https://github.com/xamarin/KimonoDesigner?files=1) hasn't been updated for a year. Note there is a WPF port, as discussed in [this article](http://lostindetails.com/blog/post/SkiaSharp-with-Wpf) and [sample on GitHub](https://github.com/8/SkiaSharp-Wpf-Example).

Comment: Your link does not work, pls fix it. Thanks